# using where_in codeigniter multidimensional array

Tags: php, sql, arrays, codeigniter

can this be possible using multi dimensional array in where_in codeigniter

```
 $arr = array(
        array(
            'recipient_id' => 1,
            'group_id' => 26,
            ),
        array(
            'recipient_id' => 3,
            'group_id' => 26,
            ),
        array(
            'recipient_id' => 4,
            'group_id' => 26,
            ),
        );
```

Comment: no this is not possible in CI

Answer (score 0):

I am not so clear but in codeigniter the where in can be written as follows:

```
$arr=array('test','test1');
$this->db->or_where_in('name', $arr);
```